# Undesirable result when cutting by year in R

Tags: r

There is an undesirable feature in function `cut.Date`, which when applied on Dec 31 will add next year as a level:

```
cut(as.Date("2013-12-31"), "year")
[1] 2013-01-01
Levels: 2013-01-01 2014-01-01
```

This causes me a lot of troubles when processing data later, I wonder whether there is any alternative to cut data by year without this weird feature?

Comment: It's because of this line in `cut.Date`: `end <- as.POSIXlt(end + (366 * step * 86400))`. Presumably it uses 366 rather than 365 to deal with leap years. I'm sort of surprised that a more elegant solution isn't used, but then again doing anything with dates correctly 100% of the time is almost impossible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If `x` is your date vector, you can remove empty levels as follows:

```
x = droplevels(x)
```

There may be a way to avoid the creation of an empty level in the first place, but at least this is a simple way to get rid of it.

Using your example:

```
droplevels(cut(as.Date("2013-12-31"), "year"))
[1] 2013-01-01
Levels: 2013-01-01
```

Another option is to directly extract the year from the date object. For example:

```
library(lubridate)
year(as.Date(c("2013-12-31","2014-12-09","2014-11-10")))

[1] 2013 2014 2014
```

This won't be a factor, but you can always convert it to one if you'd like.

Comment: This is a good answer but I feel that this brings up a common recommendation I keep saying. If you don't explicitly need factors don't use them.